# How to customize management endpoint path in HashiCorp Consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, consul

If I try to customize the management endpoint of a **Spring Boot Consul** application to other path, for example:

```
management.context-path=/manage
```

**HashiCorp Consul server** can not detect if the microservice is working fine.
Is there any to inform Consul server what endpoint path should look for?

If I comment the property "management.context-path", Consul server works fine again, because goes back to root endpoint path.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after looking for a while on the Internet I found out the answer:

```
management:
  context-path: /manage

spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckPath: /manage/health
```

Source:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc